# Easy way of finding out whether or not a sub-triangle exists

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, problem-solving

If i have a triangle similar to Pascal's triangle, except instead of row 1 and row 2 of the triangle being composed entirely of 1s, they are comprised of 3 random numbers, like this one here:

(row 1 is the top, row 2 is the row under that (the one that contains 9 and 3), and etcetera)

[image: Like this]

Then, if i know only the numbers on row 1 and 2 (4, 9 and 3), is there an easy way for me to find out whether or not a sub-triangle, which is a smaller triangle contained in the larger triangle, exists, without reconstructing the larger triangle?

I.e., In this example, the sub-triangle (21, 30, 36) exists (in orange):

[image]

Then, if i know only the numbers on row 1 and row 2, is there any easy way that I can find out whether or not the sub-triangle (21, 30, 36), exists, without reconstructing the larger triangle?

Comment: Your numbers must satisfy similar properties as numbers from the standard binomial triangle. For instance, [diagonals in pascals triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#Diagonals) satisfy $\binom{n+d-1}{d}$, while in your triangle, if your main triangle is given by $(x, a, b)$ as first two rows, then the $n$-th number in the $d$-th left-to-right diagonal (starting at $d,n=0$ for $d\gt 0$) is given by $ P_d(n)= a\binom{n+d-1}{d-1} + b\binom{n+d-1}{d} $.